# Swift outlet collection - 'IBOutlet' property cannot be an array of non-'@objc' class type

Tags: swift, iboutletcollection

I'm trying to setup an outlet collection in swift. The problem is I am getting the following error :

> 'IBOutlet' property cannot be an array of non-'@objc' class type '[Badge]'

Here is my code :

```
import UIKit

class BadgeModuleCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet var badges: [Badge]!
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong ? This seems to be the same as in the Apple documentation ([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html)).

Comment: Can you post the definition of `Badge`? It looks like `Badge` is a struct, not a class.

Comment: Urg, my bad, you made me find it ! I had a custom view called Badge, that I renamed to BadgeView to define a class from scratch called Badge... Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going wrong. I initially had a class called "Badge" that was a custom UIView. All was fine. Then I renamed it into "BadgeView" to allow me declare a new class called "Badge" from scratched. So here my outlet collection was supposed to contain object that are not outlet, which has no sense. I renamed `@IBOutlet var badges: [Badge]!` to `@IBOutlet var badges: [BadgeView]!` and all is working now.